# Password_verfiy in PHP fails

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I am using password_hash on the password and then storing it in a DB. Then when I am using password_verify to check the PW.
My code keeps failing when I use records from my DB.  When I hard code the data into the password_verify function, the function returns a True that the password was verified. I'm stumped about this. Where am I going wrong in the process?

My Code:

```
if(password_verify($_POST["password"],$storedpwd)) {
     echo "Password is valid!<br>";
} else {
echo "Invalid password.";
}
```

Again if I replace *$_POST["password"]* and *$storedpwd* with actual data the function works. So where am I going wrong on this?

Comment: Is the database column something like 255 chars? Would also be useful to have the code which fetches the stored password.

Comment: 255 chars would be sufficient, according to the PHP manual

Comment: _"if I replace $_POST["password"] and $storedpwd with actual data the function works"_ Then either `$_POST["password"]` or `$storedpwd` is not what you think it is. Run var_dump() to verify.

Comment: You're most likely getting it wrong in the code you're not showing us. The population of your variables...

Comment: I assume you stored $storedpwd after hashing it with password_hash($password)? Dump both values and you should be able to see what's happening.

Comment: I have changed the DB column from 128 to 255.

Comment: Thanks so much. I made a stupid mistake on my part. I forgot about variable scope.